# Cannot reopen closed application on emulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I'm making my first iPhone app. I could solve most of my problems browsing stackoverflow and apple's doc. But now I'm stuck. it's probably a stupidity, but I don't find it.

When I start my app on the emulator using [x]-r I don't have problems. 
But **after my aplication go in the background** (close?) because user press the home button or because I open the browser(app openURL:), **I cannot reopen it again from the emulato**r ("touching" the icon on the emulator).

I belive I'm missing something about when/how to create/reload the view/viewController.

When I try to restart the application, the logs tell me that the main function is not called. neither is the applicationDidFinishLaunching nor the viewWillAppear.
The status bar show up (animation like a normal openning) then no view show up and the application close.

My application got a windows with a fix header logo(from nib file)  and a navigationController (created dyn.).  the other view are created dyn. too (no nib). My root viewCtrl is a box for a TableViewCtrl.

Any ideas why I got this problem ?
Do you know of any good article about this issue? (I try to compare with apple's example/doc but I do not use IB)

any help appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well...

I **create a new project and copy all** my .h,h and xib (not the plist and other project's file).

This seem to do the trick.

If I found out what caused the application to close on opening, I will add a comment here.

oh, I also found out that the NSlog does not work (ie: aren't visible in the xcode debug console) if you re-open the application from the emulator. This is maybe very obvious for most of you, but this came as a surprise for me.